# Add one new value to the equation till the condition will be met

Tags: python, pandas

I'm stuck with the moment of appending new values to equation, so any help is welcome.

Assuming I have dataframe like this:

```
   Name| A | B |
     A | 30| 0 |  
     A | 15| 5 |  
     B | 10| 5 |  
     A | 94| 40|
     B | 30| 40|  
     A | 15|125|
     A | 3 |150|
```

and `c=0.01`

I want to reproduce the next rule: `A1[A]-A2[B]*c+A2[A]+...+An` WHILE `> 0`. So, since `A1[A]-A2[B]*c+A2[A] > 0` at the next step the `A3[A]` must be added to the initial equation and so on till the condition will be met
But I can't get how to append An to the end of the equation.

For now my code looks like this:

```
for a in df['Name']:
c = 0.1
shift = 1
sum = df[df['Name']=='A']['A'] - df[df['Name']=='A']['B'].shift(-1)*c + df[df['Name']=='A']['A'].shift(-shift)
while sum >0:
    shift=+1
    sum = sum+df[df['Name']=='A']['A'].shift(-shift)
```

The problem in the code that I have just computations for each pair of A-s and the output is

0     44.5
1    105.0
3     96.5
5      4.0
6      NaN

While I need the program to continue addition of the n-th A value to initial equation while the sum is >0

Comment: Do you only use the rows where Name is A?

Comment: @ansev yes. rows with B only show that there can be other records, but only As are needed

Comment: Do you want `A1[A]-A2[B]*c+A2[A]-A3[B]*c + A3[A]....`?.

Comment: @ansev nope. A1[A]-A2[B]*c+A2[A]+ A3[A] + A4[A]....

Comment: Can you provide a bit more context for this? I'm not sure I understand. How is this an equation? Why use a Pandas DataFrame?

Comment: @AMC in dataframe stored some basic calculations that must be further calculated. The point of the formula (I said it wrong in topic) is to "unite" groups of A. If the result of the formula produce positive number - A-s are in one group, if negative then another group must be started. That is why A1[A]-A2[B]*c+A2[A] is a 'constant' part of the formula and only next A's values from A column must be added.

Comment: _"unite" groups of A_? Does this formula (algorithm) have a name?

Comment: @AMC any known name. just own formula.

Comment: What do you mean by _any known name. just own formula._? It would be good to get more information on this, there is probably a better alternative to a DataFrame.

Comment: @AMC you asked about the formula name, I just said that it actually has no name. As for DF and its alternatives...well, here is just a small piece of the data, the very one that should be processed with that formula. IRL, there's a DF that contains object id, name of the event, duration and time between events. In example above Name column represents name of the event, A column its duration, B column time between events. So by formula I can get some value, that will represent if the group of events can be united (if value is +) or there's another group of A events started (if value is - or 0)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
c = 0.1
A =df.loc[df['Name'].eq('A')].reset_index(drop=True)
```

**Case 1: If the first value of `A[B]` is 0 as in the example.**

```
s = ( A['A'].sub(A['B'].mul(c))
            .where(A.index <2,A['A'])
            .cumsum() )
print(s)
0     30.0
1     44.5
2    138.5
3    153.5
4    156.5
dtype: float64
```

**Case 2: first value of A[B] isn't 0**

---

```
s = ( A['A'].sub(A['B'].mul(c).mask(A.index==0,0))
            .where(A.index <2,A['A'])
            .cumsum() )
```

---

```
s[s.le(0).cumsum().eq(0)].iloc[-1]
```

**Output**

```
156.5
```

Answer (score 1):

IIUC, you can do:

```
# extract the name A
dfA = df[df.Name=='A']

# compute cumulative sum of A1[A] - A2[B]
s = dfA['A'].sub(dfA['B'].shift(-1).mul(-c).fillna(0)).cumsum()

# find the last positive value
# might need to check if there is one
s[s.le(0).cumsum().eq(0)].iloc[-1]
```

Output:

```
160.2
```

Comment: I think the problem here is that the check is done in even terms

Comment: Why use attribute-style column access instead of `[ ]`?

Comment: It doesn't really matter to me. `[ ]` access is safer, e.g. if you have a column named `count`, then `df.count` does not give you that column.